# Extracting data from column and put them in another column

Tags: mysql

I'm having a problem with building a query.
What I have is this in THE db

```
--------------------------------------
 Id |name  | profilenr  |  nr     
--------------------------------------
  1 | Harry| admin-124  | NULL 
  2 | Barry| admin-267  | NULL
  6 | gerry| user-689   | NULL
  9 | larry| user-435   | NULL
```

What I want to do is:
Getting only the numbers from the profilenr column and put them in the nr column of each profile that starts whit admin- .
In this example only for harry 124 in colum nr
And for Barry only 267 in colum nr.
I know this is possible but don't know how to build the query for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be more like this:

```
update my_table update
set nr = substr(profilenr, locate('-', profilenr)+1, 3)
where profilenr like 'admin-%';
```

Comment: Thanks this was totaly what i  needed,

Answer (score 1):

You can use a substr and locate

```
update my_table 
set nr = substr(profilenr, locate('-',profilenr)+1, 3);
```